# How to scope dagger dependencies with fragments when using Fragment Factory?

Tags: android, android-fragments, dagger-2

Without using `FragmentFactory`, scoping dependencies within Fragment is straigth forward. Just create a `Subcomponent` for your fragment and just create the `Fragment`'s Subcomponent in `onAttach()`.

But when using `FragmentFactory` you no longer inject dependencies via the subcomponent but instead pass then in `Fragment`'s constructor.

I was wondering if I could still declare a dependency which should only last within the fragment's lifecycle using `Dagger`. I currently could not think of a way to achieve this.

So instead of binding my dependencies to a certain scope, I just declare the dependency with any scope or just use `@Reusable` on them.

Also, since fragments are created through `FragmentFactory`, the created `Fragments` doesn't exist in the DI graph.

How can we properly scope dependencies to fragment and also be able to add the fragment in the DI graph when using `FragmentFactory`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by making a `Subcomponent` responsible for creating your `Fragment`.  The `Fragment` should have the same scope as this `Subcomponent`.

```
@Subcomponent(modules = [/* ... */])
@FragmentScope
interface FooSubcomponent {

    fun fooFragment(): FooFragment

    @Subcomponent.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(): FooSubcomponent
    }
}
```

After taking care of any cyclic dependency issues, this `Subcomponent` acts the same as if you had explicitly created a subcomponent in `onAttach()` using `@BindsInstance`, except that you can (and must) now use constructor injection on `FooFragment`.

In order to provide `FooFragment` in your main component (or parent subcomponent), you will need to install this `Subcomponent` into a module.

```
@Module(subcomponents = [FooSubcomponent::class])
object MyModule {
    @Provides
    @IntoMap
    @FragmentKey(FooFragment::class)
    fun provideFooFragment(factory: FooSubcomponent.Factory): Fragment {
        return factory.create().fooFragment()
    }
}
```

Some caveats:

1. The scenario you describe (`FooFragment` depends on some class which depends on `FooFragment`) is the definition of a cyclic dependency.  You will need to inject a `Lazy` or `Provider` at some point in this cycle, or Dagger will throw an error at compile time.
2. If you split this up into two steps, first providing `FooFragment` and then binding it into your map, the subcomponent will see the `@Provides` method from its parent component.  This is likely to cause a `StackOverflowError` if you aren't careful.

Comment: I see thank you very much. This is very informative.

Comment: hi @Nitrodon, I was just wondering if you got any tips when doing this for child fragments?

Comment: Sounds good) What about @ContributesAndroidInjector?